# Visual studio "module unsafe for SAFESEH image" occurring when building release in Assembly/C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, seh

I've been following this youtube tutorial to begin learning about Assembly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3roB5sRg4o&list=PLRwVmtr-pp05c1HTBj1no6Fl6C6mlxYDG&index=2

And everything's been going fine until I switch the build from debug to release, returning two errors: "module unsafe for SAFESEH image", and "unable to generate SAFESEH image". The thing is that I've deleted everything except for the External Dependencies folder, meaning that I don't have a vast selection of properties to choose from.

Here's a screenshot to my Visual Studio environment:

[image: A screenshot of me on visual studio going through the errors.]

And here's another screenshot of my properties:

[image: My visual studio properties]

I'm a bit confused, since some other forums say to just change a setting, but since I deleted those default project folders I don't have it. Or is it something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like you're looking at the Solution's properties, instead of the project's properties, where what you are looking for is most likely found. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Right, since your assembler file does not have exception handling, you need to turn off the /SAFESEH switch in the linker properties.  Also, your assembler module does not have a `ret` statement, so it's just going to flow into random memory.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the insight! This is quite literally my first ever time even touching the syntax of assembly, so I'll add that.

Comment: @ChrisMM Yeah, I also realized that a few days after posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a comment saying to replace the old build command from `ml /c /Cx /coff "%(FullPath)"` to `ml /c /Cx /coff /safeseh "%(FullPath)"` (notice the addition of `/safeseh`), which resolved the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you need to *add* `/safeseh`?  Wouldn't that enable it, and thus require object files that have SEH metadata?